# vue-router vuejs how to change the props in child component via vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How to change the props passed in the child component of the vue-router?

I use the vue-cli to generate a webpack project, but I am new to vue-router.
I know it uses *$emit* and *$on* to change between the child component and parent component, but how to change the props passed in the child component of the vue-router? I have no idea which is the top element.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic routes with params:

http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Comment: I don't mean that. I find I misunderstand of how vue-router works. Each view defined in the router doesn't consists of parent-child component, they are sibling.